# Android fragments loading slowly

Tags: android, android-fragments

My Activity contains one listview (left side) and one fragment container to the right (fill_parent)
In the container, I want to load about 10 fragments.

The activity is supposed to act like a settings page, in the left side (listview) you choose an action/category and in the right "panel" you see the multiple options that are available for that category.

The code works fine, except the fragments are not all loaded when the activity is shown, so if I click on a category (listview item on the left), the container (right side) does not show it's contents. After clicking on multiple items in the left side... eventually ... the right side starts to show what it should from the start.

My question is, how can I display some Toast at the start of the activity, that will remain onscreen until all fragments are loaded?

So the relevant code is bellow:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.id_lista_optiuni); // the left-side listview
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        String[] values = new String[] { "Category one",
                "Category two",
                "Category three",
                ... (here are the rest values of course)
                "Category ten"
        };


        lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        lv.setItemChecked(1, true);

        MySimpleArrayAdapter adapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(this, values); // here the adapter generates the design of the left listview
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            // Here I restore last state for checked position.
            mCurCheckPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("curChoice", 0);
        }
        lv.setItemChecked(mCurCheckPosition, true);
        lv.setSelected(true);

        FragmentTransaction transa = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            mymerc= (merc_fragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("merc");
            if (mymerc == null) {
                mymerc = new merc_fragment ();
                transa.add(R.id.frag_container, mymerc, "merc");
            }
            mysort= (sort_fragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("sort");
            if (mysort == null) {
                mysort = new sort_fragment ();
                transa.add(R.id.frag_container, mysort, "sort");
            }
            ... // here follow the rest of the fragments
            ... // and now I decide which fragment I hide and which one I put on display
            transa.hide(mymerc);
            transa.hide(myment);
            ... (all other fragments get hidden except one)
            fragmentOnDisplay = mysort;
        transa.commit();

        // next I have the onItemClick event where I decide which fragment to display and display it.
```

So this is the code, and it works, but like I said, it takes a while to load all fragments (probably), so when the user is presented with the left side "menu" listview, if he starts right away clicking on items, nothing displays in the right side.

Please do not recommend that I use NavigationDrawer or TABHost or other approaches. This is the one I want, it's simple and straightforward. 
Please help me achieve this. All I want is a message that will notify the user that the fragments are done loading.

Thank you

Comment: Well, mainly because I want the user to have all the fragments available for fast switching between them. Also I need to be able to save their state so I wont create the fragment each time the user clicks on an item. I only want to create the fragments ONCE, then switch between them. The categories (listview items) are all part of one big action. Think of it like this: the user visits a client and has to enter about 20-30 pieces of information about that visit. The pieces of information are grouped in 10 groups. But all of them are necessary, so I can't let him enter one info and then save...

Comment: The last item of the listview is "Save visit". So after the user enters info in all 9 other fragments, he presses "Save" and then I check to make sure he entered all NECESSARY fields and allow him (or not) to save the visit. Only then I free the fragments. Also the information pieces are not simple editTexts, so I cannot include all fields in one biiig fragment. Some of the fragments deal with local SQLite tables getting info from them. Basically every fragment is complex.

Comment: So? Ant thoughts on how can I display a notification while the fragments are loading?

Comment: Ok So an indeterminate progress dialog... how can I implement that in my code so that I can hide it when it's over? How do I know all the fragments are done being created?